# I have a table with column contains a request from an API that contains special characters and it looks like

Tags: sql, json, oracle

```json
{
  "Info": {
    "code": "SPPACK"
  },
  "user": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "login": {
      "loginType": "MOBILE_NUMBER",
      "userName": "91817343123"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve only `LoginType` and `Username` values from the JSON above such as

| LoginType | Username |
| --- | --- |
| MOBILE_NUMBER | 91817343123 |

How can I write a query in oracle to retrieve these values? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON_TABLE()` function such as

```sql
SELECT LoginType, userName
  FROM t,
       JSON_TABLE(jstr, '$'
                        COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$."user"[*]."login"[*]'
                        COLUMNS (
                                 LoginType VARCHAR2 PATH '$."loginType"', 
                                 userName  VARCHAR2 PATH '$."userName"') 
                   ))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5116aa4bb629a7a0bbd3fccadc8173fb)</kbd>

Comment: It worked. TY :)